# Prestashop third party application login for customers

Tags: android, ios, authentication, oauth-2.0, prestashop-1.7

Hello i am trying to login a customer from a third party application using Prestashop web service.
i want to know if prestashop has this ability in their web service and what **secure_key** in **ps_customer** table is used for or can i decrypt the hashed password ??

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve information via the Prestashop webservice (see documentation here: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service), but you can not decrypt the passwords, they are encrypted in MD5 in the database with a unique Hash present in the setting.inc file. Php in the config folder at the root of the prestashop site.

Regards

Comment: I already checked the documentation before but i can't find a useful resource to achieve the authentication is there a possibility to use Oauth 2.0 authentication ??